# sugarcrm REST get_entry

Tags: rest, sugarcrm

Can someone take a look at how I've set up this REST call?  I haven't been able to find an example of this, and I can't get it to work.

It may be the blank 'link_name_to_fields_array' parameter.  I have read the documentation and don't really understand that parameter.  I don't know if that is causing my problem or not.

Any help would be apprecitated.

```
//SET UP CURL
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//parameters for get_entry call (I received a session id from a call to the login function.  Using it here)
//I manually got this user 'id' form the sugarcrm database
$parameters = array(
         'session'=>$result->id,
         'module_name' => 'users',
         'id' => '21a6a633-40de-9bf4-aa14-4f8753ea5aa2',
         'select_fields' => array('user_name'),
         'link_name_to_fields_array'=> array()
 );


$json = json_encode($parameters);
$postArgs='method=get_entry&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON$rest_data=' . $json;
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArgs);
$result2 = curl_exec( $curl );
echo("<pre>" . print_r($result2,true) . "</pre>");
```

The output is "**Bad data passed in; Return to Home**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the postArgs line (replace `$rest_data` with `&rest_data`). Try with this:

```
$postArgs='method=get_entry&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data=' . $json;
```